# WPF - StrokeDashArray with percentage values

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

When using WPF, you can draw StrokeDashArrays using `StrokeDashArray="1,10,5,5"` etc.

However, I am using the StrokeDashArray-Property on a ellipse shape and I do not want to calculate all double values when drawing this ellipse.

Is it possible to somehow use percentage values?
Something like `StrokeDashArray="10%, 50%, 25%, 15%"`...

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to append my definition of `percentage` in this context: The percentage of the complete line.

e.g.:
If you have a circle/ellipse with a radius of 100px, the circumference would be `2π * 100` and the value `10%` would be `2π * 100px * 0.1 = 62.8px`. These 62.8px should be the length of the corresponding segment, which is represented by the 10%

Comment: What are they percentages of?

Comment: @GlenThomas: I edited my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `Width` property of the `Ellipse` and user a converter to calculate the stroke dash array. If the `Ellipse` is not a circle, I'm not sure what you want to happen in that case...

```
<Ellipse StrokeDashArray="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource EllipseStrokeConverter}}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

The converter:

```
public class EllipseStrokeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var width = (double)value;

        var strokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection();

        strokeDashArray.Add(CalculatePercentage(width, 0.1));
        strokeDashArray.Add(CalculatePercentage(width, 0.5));
        strokeDashArray.Add(CalculatePercentage(width, 0.25));
        strokeDashArray.Add(CalculatePercentage(width, 0.15));

        return strokeDashArray;
    }

    private double CalculatePercentage(double width, double percent)
    {
        return 2 * 3.14 * (width / 2) * percent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```